# PHP can't "see" a oracle table

Tags: php, oracle

)

I've implemented the oci Extension, and i can connect to the database.

but i can't do anything with the database :-(

on every query i get table or view not found.

i've tried to write a quick test to proof that it works in php:

```
<?php
    $conn = oci_connection("user", "pass", "localhost/xe");
    $stdi = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tests WHERE STATUS =110");
    echo oci_execute($stdi);
```

and get the ORA-00942 Error.

I wrote the same statement inside the sqlDevelopper:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from tests where status = 110;
```

And get a result.

it seems like i have the wrong "database" but as i know oracle doesn't work with seperate databases like MySQL.

I run Oracle Express 11 and have already granted all to the user.

Thanks

Comment: Are you logging in as the same user in both cases?  Does the user that you are logging in as own the table?

Comment: Try prefixing the name of the table with the database name e.g:
SELECT COUNT(*) from yourDatabase.tests where status = 110;

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved.

I've granted the wrong user the rights.

Now with the right user everything is fine :-)